# How to post status on Twitter ad HTML?

Tags: twitter

HI I'm using Twitterizer2 library to update my status on twitter. Is there any way post it as HTML? I tried but it's not rendering html tags.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put: you can't do this.

Twitter doesn't want you to do this, so none of the twitter clients (including twitter.com itself) will render HTML. Your HTML will get escaped on display and render as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

yea the best thing you are can do if you are wanting to use any kind of code at all since twitter was made for microbloggin and fast loading is sign up for like a wordpress or whatever and send people to there using the twitter. like @ITNetwork is what i use for posting articles off my site and it just gives the title and the url and if people wanna see it they just click on it.